# Prove the group is abelian

Tags: group-theory

> Let $(G, \cdot)$ be a group such that the functions $f: G \rightarrow
>  G, f(x)=x^{m+1}$ and $g: G \rightarrow G, g(x)=x^{n+1}$ are surjective
>   endomorphisms (where $n,m$ are positive coprime integers). Prove $G$
>   is comutative.

My attempt:

Since $f$ endomorfism $(xy)^{m+1}=x^{m+1}y^{m+1}$ therefore $(yx)^m=x^my^m$

Also $(yx)^{m+1}=y^{m+1}x^{m+1}$ therefore $yxx^my^m=y^{m+1}x^{m+1}$ and $x^{m+1}y^m=y^mx^{m+1}$

Since $f$ surjective, it follows $ay^m=y^ma, \forall a,y \in G$

Analogous for $g$, $ay^n=y^na, \forall a,y \in G$

If I can prove $G=\{y^n, y \in G\}$ or $G=\{y^m, y \in G\}$ it's done, but I cannot do it. Also I find dubious the fact that I never used $n,m$ are coprime, maybe something is wrong with my reasoning.

Comment: I don't see how you got $ay^m=y^ma$.

Comment: @Shaun Because $x^{m+1}$ generates $G$

Comment: Does it? I don't see how, I'm afraid; is it because $f$ is surjective?

Comment: @Shaun Yes.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To finish your proof, note that there are integers $r$, $s$ with $1=rm+sn$ so that $y=(y^m)^r(y^n)^s$. As $y^m$ and $y^n$ commute with $a$, then so does any element in the group they generate, in particular $y$.

Comment: Nice, I was so close ..

Comment: Eugeni, so very very close! My advice would be that as soon as you see " $m$ and $n$ are coprime " you should always write down @Lord Shark's "note that there are integers $r, s$ with $1=rm+sn$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Right, thank you for the advice, it's very useful.